# Rails 3: Template Missing error. How to only render a flash message after a create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to render only a flash message without a redirect or render after a Create action:

```
  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(params[:subscriber])
    if @subscriber.save
      success = true
      message = "Thanks!"
    else
      success = false
      message = "Sorry, there was an error."
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        if success
          flash[:success] = message 
        else
          flash[:error] = message
        end  
      }  
    end
  end
```

With this code I get a Template Missing error. I don't want to refresh the same page either. How do I show the flash message without refreshing the page and without getting the template error?

Comment: I think "Ajax" would be the right solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027282/rails-3-submit-remote-form-via-jquery-prevent-page-from-reloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't redirect_to any other action, then you should have a view named `create.html`

The common practice here is to redirect somewhere like root_path, or to subscriber profile or whatever

And yes, to show just flash message, you could use AJAX, then you controller action will look smth like:

```
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(params[:subscriber])
  success_msg, error_msg = "Thanks!", "Sorry, there was an error."

  respond_to do |format|
    if @subscriber.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, :success => success_msg }
      format.js { render :js => your_javascript_to_show_the_message_here }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, :error => error_msg }
      format.js { render :js => your_javascript_to_show_the_message_here }
    end
  end 
end
```